# How to hide an individual CodeLens upon click?

Tags: tensorflow, vscode-extensions

Say if I have several codeLens like below and I want to hide them when I click. How do I do this? Seems the `vscode.CodeLensProvider` doesn't support this?

[image]

Comment: Please, never post images of code, but the code itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it at https://github.com/dcastro/vscode-haskell-test-runner/commit/ee08bd1b4ec86474597b22ee6e07e71732b5426c

Basically add an event emitter to the provider.